# Regex for repeating tag=value blocks

Tags: python, regex

I have a dataset with lines of tag=value pairs that is delimited by | (\x01). Below is an example of a single line:

120=3|162=0|181=1|72=24842|23=125|40=119|155=2321|130=3|105=1|4562=1|162=2|181=1|72=24842|23=125|40=120|155=2322|130=5|105=1|4562=2|162=0|181=1|72=24842|23=125|40=121|155=2326|130=2|105=1|4562=10|100=087|\n

What i want to do is use a regular expression to capture each repeating block - each starts with tag 162 and ends with tag 4562, the in-between tags are always the same too - and place it in a list.

The output of the above example should be the following:

```
['162=0 181=1 72=24842 23=125 40=119 155=2321 130=3 105=1 4562=1',     
'162=2 181=1 72=24842 23=125 40=120 155=2322 130=5 105=1 4562=2', 
'162=0 181=1 72=24842 23=125 40=121 155=2326 130=2 105=1 4562=10']
```

I have experimented with variations of the following expression:

```
re.findall("(?:^|\x01)(162)=(.*?)(?=\x01)", line)
```

It captures the individual tag=value pairs correctly but i haven't been able to find the correct expression to "glue" them together in order to get the output described above.

Note that each line starts with a tag that informs us about the number (1 to N) of repeating blocks contained. In this particular case it is 3 as seen from tag 120=3.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This data seems so well-structured, a regular expression seems both overkill and harder to maintain than simply parsing the thing into a python data structure and then manipulating/formatting it however you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure Python solution, no regex needed:

```
def parse_data(data):
    result, current = [], []  # storage for our final result and current sublist
    pairs = data.split("|")  # lets first turn everything to key-value pairs
    for pair in pairs:
        if current or pair[:4] == "162=":
            current.append(pair)  # add to the current sublist
            if pair[:5] == "4562=":  # end tag, finalize the block
                result.append(current)  # add the sublist to our main result
                current = []  # reinitialize sublist
    return [" ".join(current) for current in result]  # finally, space separate the pairs

parsed = parse_data(line)
# ['162=0 181=1 72=24842 23=125 40=119 155=2321 130=3 105=1 4562=1',
#  '162=2 181=1 72=24842 23=125 40=120 155=2322 130=5 105=1 4562=2',
#  '162=0 181=1 72=24842 23=125 40=121 155=2326 130=2 105=1 4562=10']
```

You should probably go with `regex`, tho - I imagine it would be faster on CPython. As a procedure, the 'pure Python' is simpler than what the `regex` engine has to do, but the `regex` engine runs on the C layer while most of the above code is interpreted so...

**UPDATE** - However, we can procedurally still beat `regex`, consider this one:

```
def parse_data_optimized(data):
    result = []  # storage for our result
    start = 0  # where to start searching our string
    while True:
        start = data.find("162=", start)  # find the next 162 tag
        end = data.find("4562=", start)  # find the following 4562 tag
        end = data.find("|", end)  # find the key-value separator after the end tag
        if start == -1 or end == -1:  # if either search failed nothing more to search
            break
        result.append(data[start:end].replace("|", " "))  # slice's '|'->' ', add to result
        start = end  # set our next search to start from the end of the current one
    return result  # return the result
```

Benchmarks on your data (using degant's regex for comparison, all on CPython):

```
# Python 3.5.1
zwer_1: 100,000 loops: 1.138 seconds
zwer_2: 100,000 loops: 0.515 seconds
regexp: 100,000 loops: 0.772 seconds

# Python 2.7.11
zwer_1: 100,000 loops: 0.833 seconds
zwer_2: 100,000 loops: 0.431 seconds
regexp: 100,000 loops: 0.763 seconds
```

Comment: Interesting, your optimised version is indeed about ~50% faster than regex  in my machine too. Considering that the files i'm working with are huge, that speed-up is non trivial. I've upvoted both of you but it seems that i'll be using your solution after all!

Answer (score 2):

Using a bit of regex and then `str.replace()`:

```
>>> result = re.findall(r'\b162=\d+(?:\|\d+=\d+)+?\|4562=\d+', line)
>>> result = [l.replace('|', ' ') for l in result]
>>> print(result)
['162=0 181=1 72=24842 23=125 40=119 155=2321 130=3 105=1 4562=1', 
 '162=2 181=1 72=24842 23=125 40=120 155=2322 130=5 105=1 4562=2', 
 '162=0 181=1 72=24842 23=125 40=121 155=2326 130=2 105=1 4562=10']
```

The regex verifies the format as described in the question. Then `str.replace` helps convert `|` to single spaces `' '`.

Regex: `\b162=\d+(?:\|\d+=\d+)+?\|4562=\d+`

- `\b162` matches word boundary followed by 162 so that 2162 etc don't match
- `=\d+` matches equal `=` followed by at least one number
- `(?:\|\d+=\d+)+?` is a non capturing group that allows any number of `|` followed by digits, `=`, digits i.e format |N=N
- `\|4562=\d+` matches the last part i.e `|` followed by 4562, `=` and digits

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gqoFG7/2/)